# How to get row value inside updateItem() of CellFactory

Tags: java, javafx

```
ageColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Person, String>(){
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        param.getCellFactory().
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : String.valueOf(item));

        if(person.getName.equals("MATEUS")) {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        }
    }
});
```

How to get this "Person" which is the row value from the Table? I can only get the value from the cell, but not the entire object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do

```
Person person = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
```

You can also do

```
Person person = (Person) getTableRow().getItem();
```

but this is less desirable (in my opinion) because `getTableRow()` returns a raw type, and consequently it requires the unchecked downcast.

Obviously either of these only works if `empty` is `false`, so they should be inside a check for that:

```
ageColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Person, String>(){
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            setText(item);
            Person person = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            if(person.getName.equals("MATEUS")) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
            } else {
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `getTableRow().getItem()` sometimes returns null, while `getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex())` returns expected object. My case was in `updateItem(..)`, Kotlin.

Comment: @BingLi224 Unless you are explicitly putting null values into your table's items list, `getTableRow().getItem()` will not return null in a non-empty cell.